# Dynamically updating a figure with an image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My goal is to update an image after putting it through a filter. The image is represented as a numpy Array, and displayed with pyplot in a figure.

So far, I have tried changing the interactive mode, and calling `draw()` on the figure. However after doing some research, it was to my understanding that `draw()` is not necessary if you are using `plt` functions in interactive mode.

I can have it so I repeatedly show a new figure, but I'd like to update the current one so I can keep it in one window.

This is where I initially display the image:

```py
# populating pixelData
self.pixelData = cv.imread(filename)
self.pixelData = cv.cvtColor(self.pixelData, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.ion()
self.image_figure.figimage(self.pixelData, resize=True)
self.image_figure.show()
```

and then I have a function to call after changing pixelData with one of our filters:

```py
def update_display(self):
    self.image_figure.clf()
    self.image_figure.figimage(self.pixelData, resize=True)
```

So, to recap, I want to open up an image, then with my cli tool, modify `self.pixelData`, then have the displayed image update to reflect the change in `self.pixelData`